# How can I update a UILabel as I slide my UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a UILabel and a UISlider in my app and I have it hooked up in a way that when the user changes the value of the slider and then let's go, the UILabel gets updated with the new double value.

I need to know how to update the label as the user slides the slider and not only when they let go.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `UISlider`'s `continuous` property to `YES`.

Comment: hahaha wow! I can't believe it was that simple thank a lot, I got it to work.

Comment: That's about as easy as answers get. Enjoy!